# Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined in angular datatables

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am trying to implement angular-datatables in my project but it returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

**I am using**

> Angular js version 1.4.9.
>
> Jquery version 2.1.1
>
> DataTable version 1.10.10

**Refrence site**

> [angular-datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/gettingStarted)

**My Html Code**

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="WithAjaxCtrl as showCase"> <table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="row-border hover"></table></div>
```

**My Angular js Controller code**

```
angular.module( 'admin.package', [
'ui.router',
'ui.bootstrap',
'datatables',
'datatables.bootstrap',
'ngResource',
'plusOne'
]).controller('WithAjaxCtrl', WithAjaxCtrl);

function WithAjaxCtrl(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder,$http,UserService,localStorageService) {
      UserService.obj.get('packages/index',localStorageService.get('userkey').token).then(function (results) { 
        if(results.status==200){
        var vm = this;
        vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(results.data.packages)
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
        vm.dtColumns = [
           DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('id'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('package_name').withTitle('Packag Name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('amount').withTitle('Amount'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('package_duration').withTitle('Amount'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('currency').withTitle('validity')

        ];
        console.log(vm.dtColumns);
        console.log( vm.dtOptions);
      }else{
             alert('You are not a authorized user');
          }
        }, function(reason) {
            console.log(reason);
        });
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot use `$resource`'s as base for dataTables - if you are using `fromSource()` you must target a JSON file (or something that delivers a plain JSON array of objects) if you use a `$resource` you can map it to an array of plain objects and use it as `withOption('data', value)`, perhaps along `withDataProp()` ...

Answer (score 8):

You are passing `showCase.dtOptions` and `showCase.dtColumns` to the `datatables` directives when the page loads, but they are not declared until after your service call is completed.  One workaround for this would be to use `ng-if` to construct the html after the service call:

```
<table ng-if="showCase.authorized" datatable="" ...
```

Then in your controller, initialize the variable before calling the service, and updating it after the call is complete:

```
app.controller('WithAjaxCtrl', function WithAjaxCtrl(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, UserService) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.authorized = false;
  UserService.get()...
```

Here is a demo.  You can reproduce the error by removing the `ng-if`. http://plnkr.co/edit/XZYOEvgy1HoMYGmGdAYj?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure your `<th>` are inside of `<thead>` in your table structure.

Example:

```
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th> name </th>
     <th> email </th>
   </tr>
</thead>
```