# Datatable with angularjs not working witth dtColumns and dtOptions

Tags: angularjs, datatable

Below is my code

1) in index.html file included js and css are below

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/demo/src/archives/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-datatables/demo/src/archives/dist/css/angular-datatables.min.css" type="text/css" />
```

2) app.js

```
var app1 = angular.module('app', ['datatables']);
```

3) in app\modules\curd_datatable\curd.controller.js

```
'use strict';
curdController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 'config', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder', ];
function curdController($scope, config, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
      .withOption('ajax', {
        url: 'data.json',
        type: 'GET'
      })
      .withDataProp('data')
      .withOption('serverSide', true)
      .withOption('processing', true)
      .withOption('order', [[0, 'asc'], [1, 'asc']])
      .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
    $scope.dtColumns = [
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name').notVisible()
    ];

}


module.exports = curdController;
```

4) app\modules\curd_datatable\curd.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">    
        <div ng-controller="curdController as showCase">
            <table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="row-border hover"></table>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

5) app\modules\curd_datatable\index.js

```
angular.module('app').controller('curdController', require('./curd.controller'));
```

6) app\modules\curd_datatable\data.json

```
[{
    "id": 860,
    "firstName": "Superman",
    "lastName": "Yoda"
}, {
    "id": 870,
    "firstName": "Foo",
    "lastName": "Whateveryournameis"
}, {
    "id": 590,
    "firstName": "Toto",
    "lastName": "Titi"
}, {
    "id": 803,
    "firstName": "Luke",
    "lastName": "Kyle"
}
]
```

it gives me error as below,

```
angular.min.js:116 TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Datatables : Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454203/jquery-datatables-cannot-read-property-adatasort-of-undefined)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined in angular datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980700/cannot-read-property-adatasort-of-undefined-in-angular-datatables)

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP? I don't see any PHP here...

Comment: in above suggested link by @RameshRajendran ,it not used angular datatable with properly follow angularjs for datatable with dtColumns and dtOptions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change the sequence of scripts in **`index.html`**

**Updated index.html**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/demo/src/archives/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-datatables/demo/src/archives/dist/css/angular-datatables.min.css" type="text/css" />
```

**app\modules\curd_datatable\curd.controller.js**

The sequence of components should be same in the controller.

*Replace:*

```
function curdController($scope, $http, $state, config, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
```

*With:*

```
function curdController($scope, config, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
```

*Final Code*

```
'use strict';
curdController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$state', 'config', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder'];
function curdController($scope, $http, $state, config, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
      .withOption('ajax', {
        url: 'data.json',
        type: 'GET'
      })
      .withDataProp('data')
      .withOption('serverSide', true)
      .withOption('processing', true)
      .withOption('order', [[0, 'asc'], [1, 'asc']])
      .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
    $scope.dtColumns = [
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name').notVisible()
    ];

}


module.exports = curdController;
```

**app\modules\curd_datatable\curd.html**

Remove `ng-controller` and `showCase` as we do not need it to access controller variables.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="row-border hover"></table>
    </div>
</div>
```